# Bundling PHP MySql with Flex to be given to a client

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, xampp

```
I made an application using Flex,php,mysql. Now to give it
to a client, I am bundling this flex application with
xampp. There are few problems with this approach : 

1. Whenever the flex application runs, an xampp window
also opens up.
2. The Apache port number, which I am giving to the client
is fixed. Same for mysql port number.

What could be a better alternative to overcome these?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to make a desktop-like app right? If so, your approach was the wrong one. AIR lets you access a local sqlite database, so you don't need to write serverside code at all. Now, that's kind of a lame thing to hear now that you're already done, but if you'll always have some quirks if you go your current direction.

Comment: But there is one problem with using sqllite. A promise of Flex, that the code written in Flex is easily usable across an offline or an online application, is broken.

Comment: All too true. Unfortunately, there's no good solution for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a web application *(for instance, if you application has to be accessible by many people, from any computer in the world that has access to the Internet)*, it should be deployed on a web-server somewhere, and not on your client's desktop machine.

As a sidenote : in that cas, you'll probably have to deal with some kind of authentication mecanism, to make sure only the "right people" have access to it.

There are loads of hosting companies out there ; depending on your exact needs, many of those would probably be OK for you : PHP+MySQL is quite common nowadays ; just note they generally run PHP on Linux, and not Windows, which might imply some little differences *(like case-sensitivity in files names, for instance)*

Depending on the type of company your client works in, maybe they already have some hosting possibilities ?

In that case, they should deploy the application on one of their webservers, which would make it accessible to anyone on the company *(depending on their configuration, but that's why webservers exist, after all)*

If that didn't help, could you elaborate a bit more on your needs ?

Thanks **:-)**

---

If you are building some kind of desktop application, that needs to be installed on only one computer and used by one personn and no more... Well, PHP is not the best tool for that ^^